# Why my extension sends duplicates on request in geometric progression?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I've created extension that makes some JSON request & send it to some receiver.
My problem is:
Open popup window
After it closing, extensions sends 1 request

Open it on the same page again, and extension will send 2 requests

Open again, 4 requests

Open again, 8 requests

In each uses of popup, extension will be duplicate outgoing data in geometric progression.

Why that happens?

From the panel I'm send addnewurl to the port:

```
    AddDialog.port.on("addnewurl", function (data) {
{
AddDialog  is my popup
here It handle port messages aftre popup is closed(hidded)
}
        var http = require("sdk/request").Request;
        var req = CreateRequest("add_url", {});

        req.params = {...};

        var sreq = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(req));
        count += 1; //Global counter, u will see it in video
        console.log('count = '+count);

        var cfg = {
            url : getRequestURL(),
            contentType : "text/html",
            content : sreq,
            onComplete : function (response) {
                var data = {
                    code : response.status,
                    body : response.json
                };
                AddDialog.port.emit("addnewurldone", data);
            }
        };

        http(cfg).post();
    });
```

For more sense I've created a AVI video record of that. See it here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/86175609/Project002.avi

1.6 MB

How to resolve that?

ADDED by request more info

That function emit addnewurl:

```
function AddNewURL() {
    var node = $("#Tree").dynatree("getActiveNode");
    if (node == null) {
        $("#ServerStatus").text(LocalizedStr.Status_NoGroupSelected);
        $("#ServerStatus").css("color", "red");
        return;
    };

    var nkey = node.data.key;
    var aImg = null;
    var data = {
        ownerId : nkey,
        name : $("#LinkTitle").val(),
        description : $("#LinkDesc").val(),
        url : $("#CurrentURL").val(),
        scrcapt:$("#ScrCaptureCB :selected").val()
    };

    $("#load").css("display", "inline");
    $("#ServerStatus").text(LocalizedStr.Status_AddURL);
    self.port.emit("addnewurl", data);
};
```

and it calls by button:

> ```
> self.port.on("showme", function onShow(data) {
> ....
>
>   document.querySelector('#BtnOk').addEventListener('click', function () {
>       AddNewURL();
>   });
>
> ...
> });
> ```

"swomme" goes from here(main.js):

> ```
> AddDialog.on("show", function () {
>   count = 0;
>   AddDialog.port.emit("showme", locTbl);
> });
>
> function addToolbarButton() {
>   var enumerator = mediator.getEnumerator("navigator:browser");
>   while (enumerator.hasMoreElements()) {
>       var document = enumerator.getNext().document;
>       var navBar = document.getElementById('nav-bar');
>       if (!navBar) {
>           return;
>       }
>       var btn = document.createElement('toolbarbutton');
>       btn.setAttribute('id', cBtnId);
>       btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
>       btn.setAttribute('class', 'FLAToolButton');
>       btn.setAttribute('image', data.url('icons/Add.png'));
>       btn.setAttribute('orient', 'horizontal');
>       btn.setAttribute('label', loc("Main_ContextMenu"));
>       btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
>           AddDialog.show();
>       }, false)
>       navBar.appendChild(btn);
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: There is not enough code here. You're asking why the "addnewurl" event is being emitted so many times, so we need to see where "addnewurl" is being emitted from and why

Comment: Currently I found solution way, but it doesn't resolve the problem, only breaks it. When popup shows, some global counter setup to 0, when request send some data, counter increases up to 1, after that if requests still goes and counter = 1 than function returns. Need other solution to fully resolve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here

```
document.querySelector('#BtnOk').addEventListener('click', function () {
  AddNewURL();
});
```

If you are running `AddDialog.port.emit("showme", locTbl);` when you click your toolbar button then you're adding a click listener to `#BtnOk` every time as well.

On the first toolbar click it will have one click listener, on the second click two, and so on. You should remove the above code from that function and only run it once.

Comment: Hm.. uoy think, I create a new popup windows at each toolbar click?

Comment: No, it's the same popup, but I think you're adding a new listener to `#BtnOk` on each toolbar click.

Comment: Basically, you need to place `addEventListener` somewhere where it will only run once, which should be the same place you create/define the popup, not where you show it.